# How is the Web API Controller's constructor called?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, controller, ioc-container, constructor-injection

According to [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/344078/ASP-NET-WebAPI-Getting-Started-with-MVC4-and-WebAP), a Controller should have a constructor that gets the interface to be implemented passed in, a la:

```
public class DuckbillsController : ApiController
{
    IDuckbillRepository _platypiRepository;

    public DuckbillsController(IDuckbillRepository platypiRepository)
    {
        if (platypiRepository == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("platypiRepository is null");
        }
        _platypiRepository = platypiRepository;
    }
}
```

But how is this constructor called? A reckon via a client calling a Web API method contained within this class, but how does it get passed the Interface type? Or does that not have to happen (constructor is not explicitly called by anyone/from anywhere)?

### UPDATE

The canonical examples show "private readonly" prepended to the Interface declaration, but that is not necessary for it to compile. Is there a compiling, I mean compelling, reason, for me to prepend "private readonly"?

Comment: In general, no code is written to explicitly call the constructor. You need to hook your DI container into the WebApi framework, and the container will use reflection to instantiate the controller. [This article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver) might help explain things.

Comment: This is actually a perfectly reasonable question and the provided answer simply says "look at this (third party tool)". The sad fact of the matter is that Microsoft does a really poor job documenting this and unfortunately it falls to the community to answer these questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The controller factory creates them for you... You need to have a look at Dependency Injection.

Try Autofac, it has a nice integration for MVC.

Comment: This was added for DI; we are using Windsor Castle.

Answer (score 19):

Since there's no documentation on this anywhere (the official docs just discuss doing it with Unity). Here's how you do it.

The `HttpConfiguration.DependencyResolver` property is an instance of `IDependecyResolver` which is basically a service locator (you ask for an instance of type, and it knows how to create it). What I would like is to provide my own controller instantiation.

Use like so:

```
config.DependencyResolver = 
   new OverriddenWebApiDependencyResolver(config.DependencyResolver)
   .Add(typeof(ScoreboardController), () => 
                                    new ScoreboardController(Messages) 
   );
```

Implemented like so:

```
/// <summary>
/// The standard web api dependency resolver cannot inject dependencies into a controller 
/// use this as a simple makeshift IoC
/// </summary>
public class OverriddenWebApiDependencyResolver : WebApiOverrideDependency<IDependencyResolver >, IDependencyResolver {
    public OverriddenWebApiDependencyResolver Add(Type serviceType, Func<object> initializer) {
        provided.Add(serviceType, initializer);
        return this;
    }
    public IDependencyScope BeginScope() => new Scope(inner.BeginScope(), provided);
    public OverriddenWebApiDependencyResolver(IDependencyResolver inner) : base(inner, new Dictionary<Type, Func<object>>()) { }
    public class Scope : WebApiOverrideDependency<IDependencyScope>, IDependencyScope {
        public Scope(IDependencyScope inner, IDictionary<Type, Func<object>> provided) : base(inner, provided) { }
    }
}
public abstract class WebApiOverrideDependency<T> : IDependencyScope where T : IDependencyScope {
    public void Dispose() => inner.Dispose();
    public Object GetService(Type serviceType) {
        Func<Object> res;
        return provided.TryGetValue(serviceType, out res) ? res() : inner.GetService(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Object> GetServices(Type serviceType) {
        Func<Object> res;
        return inner.GetServices(serviceType).Concat(provided.TryGetValue(serviceType, out res) ? new[] { res()} : Enumerable.Empty<object>());
    }
    protected readonly T inner;
    protected readonly IDictionary<Type, Func<object>> provided;
    public WebApiOverrideDependency(T inner, IDictionary<Type, Func<object>> provided) {
        this.inner = inner;
        this.provided = provided;
    }

}
```

The trick is that you actually have to implement `IDependencyScope` *twice* - once for `IDependencyResolver` and once for the scope it creates on each request.

Comment: Thanks; if I hadn't already marked another as the answer, I would choose this one.

Comment: You can always change it :) but no big deal. Just putting it here for posterity

Answer (score 6):

You have to use a dependency injection ( structuremap, ninject) whatever. If you dont want to use DI then you have to provide an overload constructor as shown below

```
public DuckbillsController():this( new DuckbillRepository())
{
}
```

Comment: This *is* supposed to be introducing DI into the class; that's why I added the constructor and its argument. So what else is necessary? We We are using Castle Windsor.

Comment: Castle Windsor supports MVC http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Windsor-tutorial-ASP-NET-MVC-3-application-To-be-Seen&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1